# Agregar archivo adjunto (imágenes) a formulario PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Necesito agregar una o varias fotos en un formulario de reportes de daños y enviarlo a un correo de Gmail pero me salen estos errores... 
1. Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\wamp64\www\aplicacionMovil\envio2.php on line 13

2. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp64\www\aplicacionMovil\envio2.php on line 33
   Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp64\www\aplicacionMovil\envio2.php on line 33

Los datos se envian correctamente, solo falta las imágenes

Formulario:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/patron_2.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reporte.css" type="text/css" media="screen">  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reporte.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quagga.min.js"></script>
    <form action="envio2.php" method="post">
        <div class="marco">
            <div class="principal">
                <br><br>
                <br><br>
                <div class="titulo"> 
                    <p>Reporta: </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Cualquier Tipo Daños</li>
                            <li>Equipos de Computo</li>
                            <li>Cañones</li>
                            <li>Sillas</li>
                            <li>Pisarrones</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="segunda"> 
                <p>Datos del Alumno</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="txt_matricula" placeholder="Matricula" require></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo"></p>
                <p><input type="email" name="txt_correo" placeholder="Correo Institucional"></p>
                <p>Datos del Reporte</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="txt_material" placeholder="Material Dañado"></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="txt_numero" placeholder="No. de Serie"></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="txt_lugar" placeholder="Lugar"></p>
                <p><input type="date" name="txt_fecha" placeholder="Fecha"></p>             
                <p><textarea name="area_descripcion" id="" cols="30" rows="10" name="" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea></p>
                <p><input type="file" name="foto" /></p>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_enviar" value="Enviar Reporte"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$matricula = strip_tags($_POST["txt_matricula"]);
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST["txt_nombre"]);
$mail = strip_tags($_POST["txt_correo"]);

$material = strip_tags($_POST["txt_material"]);
$numero = strip_tags($_POST["txt_numero"]);
$lugar = strip_tags($_POST["txt_lugar"]);
$fecha= time();
$fechaFormato = date("j/n/Y",$fecha);
$mensaje = strip_tags($_POST["area_descripcion"]);

$foto = $_FILES['foto'];

$body = 
 "Matricula: " . $matricula. 
 "<br>Nombre Completo: ". $nombre. 
 "<br>Correo Institucional: " . $mail. 
 "<br>Material Dañado: " . $material.
 "<br>Número de Serie: " . $numero.
 "<br>Lugar: " . $lugar.
 "<br>Fecha: " . $fechaFormato.
    "<br>Descripción: " . $mensaje.
    "Evidencias: " .$foto;



use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                         
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
    $mail->Username   = 'Mi usuario';                 
    $mail->Password   = 'Mi contraseña';                             
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                 
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                   

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', $nombre);
    $mail->addAddress('utreportes@gmail.com');                  

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Reporte de Daños';
 $mail->Body    = $body;
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->AddAttachment($foto['tmp_name'], $foto['name']);
    $mail->send();
 echo '<script>
  alert ("El mensaje se envió correctamente");
  window.history.go(-1);
 </script>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Bienvenido, De casualidad ya activaste los servicios de Mail de wamp?

Comment: Gracias! No creo que se deba a eso... Si trato de mandar un correo sin archivos adjuntos si se mandan correctamente... Falla cuando agrego las imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el codigo el problema esta en el **formulario**, debes incluir el atributo **enctype="multipart/form-data"** cuando subes cualquier archivo y usas la etiqueta input type="file". todo lo demas esta funcionando perfectamente!

```html
   <form action="envio2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```